# Wordpress - how to filter the added custom post through its taxonomy?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, categories, custom-taxonomy

I've added a new custom post in my functions.php, How can I sort the existing post through its taxonomy? goal is to filter the existing post when hit the specific category. here are the sample code bellow:

Added Custom Post inside the functions.php:

```
  $args = array(
   'label' => 'category',
   'public' => true,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
   'show_admin_column' => true,
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'query_var' => true
  );
   register_taxonomy('pdf_cat','pdf',$args);
```

On Page - get the taxonomy and echo it as my category options:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'pdf',
  'orderby' => 'slug',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => false
   );
  $categories = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'pdf_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
     ]);
    foreach( $categories as $category ){
      echo '<option><a class="ctg" href="'. get_category_link( $category->term_id ) .' ">' . $category->name . '</a></option>';
     }
   ?>
```

Filter the existing post through its taxonomy when hitting the specific category:

```
            <?php
              $cat = get_the_category();
              $cat = $cat[0]; 
              $catname = get_cat_name($cat->term_id); 
              $catid = get_cat_ID($catname);  
            ?>
              
            <?php
                  $paged = get_query_var('paged', 1);
                  $args = array(  
                      'post_type' => 'pdf',
                      'paged' => $paged,
                      'post_type' => 'post',
                      'cat' => $catid,
                  );
                  $query = new WP_Query($args);         
         
              global $query_string; 
              query_posts( $query_string . "&posts_per_page=15&paged=".$paged );
              while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `tax_query`

```
$pdf_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'pdf',
    'paged'       => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pdf_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $catid,
        ),
    ),
)

$pdf_data = new WP_Query( $pdf_args );
```

Find out more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/)

Comment: where this code suppose to put in?

Comment: I am having trouble on how to put the terms id to become the permalink of each categories